Preventing the progress of the reaction between nitrogen oxide and oxide anion
Please consider the following reaction leading to the formation of a species called peroxynitrite:
$$\ce{NO + 2O- → ONOO-}$$

Can adding an anion such as X- to the system prevent the formation of peroxynitrite? If yes which anion(s) can X- be?
Do you know any other way(s) to achieve this goal?


Peroxynitrite cannot be prepared this way - Although it looks like it can, it can only be prepared through the reaction of Nitric oxide with superoxide anions. Nitric oxide would react easily with superoxide anions so adding a different ion into reaction won't do much.
